# As a US Citizen, there any Aleutian Islands in the Eastern Hemisphere that I can move to?

Tags: usa, islands

The Aleutian Islands are famous for being remote islands. But they are also famous for something else: holding the northeasternmost territories in the USA.

I am already a US citizen, and live in one of the lower 48 states. I don't have the resources to move there right now, but I am curious. Is it legally and physically possible to move to any of the eastern hemisphere part of the Aleutian islands and if so which ones?

Comment: I don't think I'd actually do this, but I want to know if it's possible.

Comment: You can visit Attu for 2 weeks as part of a [birding tour](http://www.zbirdtours.com/attu/) for only USD $9000 or so.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the only definition I can think of that makes any sense in this context is "places less than 180 degrees east of the Greenwich meridian."  (Obviously, a definition taking the international date line into account isn't applicable, because under such a definition there are no Aleutian islands in the eastern hemisphere.)  Is there an alternative definition I'm overlooking?

Comment: @phoog You're spot on, I was obviously not thinking clearly (or at all) when I wrote that. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Nope.  Everything east of the 180-degree line is either a military base or part of the [Alaska Maritime National Wildlife Refuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Maritime_National_Wildlife_Refuge).

Answer (score 1):

[**Attu Island**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attu_Island) is part of the state of Alaska.

At longitude 172°E it is to the west of the 180° longitude, which places it in the eastern hemisphere geometrically.

However it is to the east of the [International Date Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line), which places it in the western hemisphere geographically.

[image]

The population of Attu in the 2010 census was 20 people, all coast guard personnel at [Attu Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attu_Station,_Alaska), but they all departed later in the year when the station closed. It then became the largest uninhabited island in the United States. Its population is currently 0.

[**Semisopochnoi Island**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisopochnoi_Island) is similarly placed, but at longitude 179°E is the easternmost location of the USA (further east than Maine) (and paradoxically not as far from Alaska's mainland as Attu).

Perhaps you could volunteer to be a coast guard on Attu.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though -- can you settle on either of those islands, or are they off limits?

Comment: The first aerial photos I looked at showed few signs of humanity on the island—no roads, buildings, only the two runways at the former coast guard station.  A Russian island about 250 miles away doesn't even have that.  But Google had better images, and there are still some roads.  Legalities aside, living there would be quite a challenge.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attu_Island

Comment: Perhaps [Shemya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemya) longitude 174°E would be a better bet. At one time there was a scheduled passenger/freight service. A former military base, it is still maintained as an emergency landing site for civil aircraft.